# How to fix unsolved reference 'vPython' in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, vpython

I want to code in VPython with Pycharm. I use the conda interpreter. But the keywords of Python are red underlined and it says: unsolved reference 'vPython' . I actually installed vPython and anaconda but it doesn't seem to recognize it. It even gives me the advice: install vPython when I press the red bulb. When I do so I get the error message:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- vpython

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda doesn't include `vpython` AFAIK. I think you'll need to get it from PyPI. You can do this by calling `pip install vpython` in your shell (terminal application on Mac).

Before that, though, make sure `pip` is pointing to Anaconda's `pip` so that the packages are installed in Anaconda's site-packages. You can check this with `which pip`. If that path isn't the path to your Anaconda install, you'll have to update your `PATH` environment variable to point to Anaconda's `pip`. This is system dependent, so we can't really help you much with this step (i.e. we don't know where your Anaconda installation is).

On Mac OSX, you can do `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/Anacondas/pip/directory"` in order to set your `PATH`.

HTH, let me know if you have any questions by commenting below.

Answer (score 0):

See vpython.org for detailed information on installing and using the vpython module.